# How many Wushu editions are there?

Tags: edition-comparison, wushu

I'm lost in various Wushu editions. Here're what I've found so far:

- Wushu
- Wushu Black Belt Edition
- Wushu Open
- Wushu Open Reloaded
- Wire-Fu, Pulp-Fu, etc.

What is the exact order in which they emerged? Are they compatible with each other? What edition is the recent one? What are its distinctive features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Four: Open, Open Reloaded, Budo, and Black Belt Edition.

The [RPGGeek page](https://rpggeek.com/rpgfamily/2531/wushu) has links to the various editions.

I'm working partially from memory, and partially from dead links saved to archive.org, so bear with me here.

As for Wire-Fu, Pulp-Fu, Celestial, Clockwork Wu-xia, etc., they're basically just supplements with ideas for how to play characters of a particular style. No special rules are included, just guidelines for coming up with various genre-specific Details - with the exception of Wire-Fu, which introduces Held Dice.

Establishing a timeline is tricky - RPGGeek says Budo came out in 2007, but the Open wiki page wasn't made until 2011 - I'll do some research and get back.

### What's different?

#### [Open](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Wushu_Open)

1. 3 Chi
2. Yin/Yang dice
3. Dice pool limit
4. Nemesis
5. Mooks (with 1 or more damage per round)
6. Traits (3-5)
7. Weaknesses
8. Scab rolls

#### [Budo](https://boardgamegeek.com/rpg/2514/budo-hard-style-wushu)

1. Unknown, I hadn't heard of it until just now and the copies aren't available on DriveThruRPG any more.

#### [Open Reloaded](https://web.archive.org/web/20150615233234/http://silverpath.pbworks.com/f/open_reloaded_basic.pdf)

Seems to be at least partially a fan-made addition to Open, per the description on [this old wiki page](https://web.archive.org/web/20081014160117/http://wiki.saberpunk.net/Wushu/FanRules) ("Open Reloaded: Fan-written expansion of the Open rules...") The below mechanics are the ones that show up in the linked PDF.

1. All of the above
2. Setbacks - debuffs you can take instead of going to 0 Chi
3. Blended Nemesis/Mook conflicts
4. Secondary Goals and Time Limits
5. Trait Features (e.g. Woodsman having both Archery and Survival)
6. Control Dice (e.g. werewolves staying unturned)
7. Held Dice (originally in Wire-Fu)
8. "Special Something" dice (e.g. a captain fighting on his own ship)
9. And finally, (the big one) Advancement.

#### [Black Belt Edition](https://danielbayn.com/wushu/)

1. Everything that's in Open, except for Scab rolls, and I believe Mooks are set at 1 damage per round.
2. A bunch of character archetypes.
3. Wyrd-Fu, Cut-Fu, more setting suggestions.